# child component Output event triggering the parent component parent node method

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using `@Output` in the child component to trigger a target method in the parent component. When i click on `(click)="viewPromotionDetails('Learn more')"` in the child component it's also triggering the `(click)="description()"`

Can someone help me how to resolve the issue,

I have also created [stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-calnch?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Thanks in advance.

`child.component.html`

```
<div>
    <div>Name </div>
    <div>Description </div>
    <div class="lear-more" (click)="viewPromotionDetails('Learn more')">Learn More</div>
</div>
```

Parent component HTML: `app.component.html`

```
    <div class="description" (click)="description()">
        <my-child (leanMore)="callLearnMore($event)"></my-child>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try   e.stopPropagation() inside viewPromotionDetails('Learn more'). Your stackblitz is not working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. sorry for stackblitz  I have updated it .  e.stopPropagation() not working .

Answer (score 0):

I would try to convert `div.lear-more` to `button` element. Div propagates its click events up to it ancestors (up to the root element).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at your parent HTML:

```
<div class="description" (click)="description()">
    <my-child (leanMore)="callLearnMore($event)"></my-child>
</div>
```

When somebody clicks on the `my-child`, they also click on the `div` parent at the same time. This is because the `my-child` is inside the `div`, **obviously**.

---

This is what I would recommend:

In your child-component.ts file, add a new `@Output` property called `description`:

```
@Output() public leanMore: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
@Output() public description: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
```

Then in the parent component template file, remove the `(click)="description()"`, and add it to the `my-child`.

```
<div class="description">
    <my-child (leanMore)="callLearnMore($event)" (description)="description()"></my-child>
</div>
```

And then, **finally**, in your child-component.html, add a click listener to the `<div>Description </div>` element. So the template file should look like this:

```
<div>
    <div>Name </div>
    <div (click)="description.emit()">Description </div>
    <div class="lear-more" (click)="viewPromotionDetails('Learn more')">Learn More</div>
</div>
```

Hopefully, this helps you and solves your problem.